# Semantic UI dropdown not able to disable using select input + AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, semantic-ui

I'm trying to disable a dropdown depending of a value of a different input. I'm working with Semantic UI and Angular.

This is my HTML

```
<select class="ui search dropdown" ng-attr-id="{{'dd-' + question.id}}"
        ng-options="option.value as option.text for option in question.options"
        ng-model="question.answer"
        ng-disabled="!question.isEnable">
</select>
```

And this is how is rendered

```
    <div class="ui search dropdown ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid selection">
    <select ng-attr-id="{{'dd-' + question.id}}" ng-options="option.value as option.text for option in question.options" ng-model="question.answer" ng-disabled="!question.c_questionIsEnable" id="dd-483" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="" class="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option label="Yes" value="string:213">Yes</option>
    <option label="No" value="string:214">No</option>
    <option label="Does not apply" value="string:547">Does not apply</option>
    </select>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i><input class="search" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0">
<div class="text"></div><div class="menu transition hidden" tabindex="-1">
<div class="item selected" data-value="string:213">Yes</div>
<div class="item" data-value="string:214">No</div>
<div class="item" data-value="string:547">Does not apply</div>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the rendered code the disabled attribute is present in the `<select>`, 
nevertheless the dropdown is not disabled. Reading the Semantic UI docs, there is a way to set a dropdown in a [disable state](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#disabled) using  the css class **disabled** but is not working either (the css class is added to the `<select>`)

HTML code with using class

```
<select class="ui search dropdown" ng-attr-id="{{'dd-' + question.id}}"
            ng-options="option.value as option.text for option in question.options"
            ng-model="question.answer"
            ng-class="{'disabled': !question.isEnable}">
    </select>
```

Indeed, the class disabled is added to the select input but the dropdown is not disabled, using Chrome Dev Tools, the element gets disabled if I add the class in the following line

```
<div class="ui search dropdown ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid selection disabled">
```

Is there a way for make this work using `<select>`?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy way to do this.

Wrapping the  in a  with the field css class, and use the ng-class attribute in there.

Hope this could help.

```
<div class="ui field" ng-class="{'disabled': !question.isEnable }"> 
<select class="ui search dropdown" ng-attr-id="{{'dd-' + question.id}}"
        ng-options="option.value as option.text for option in question.options"
        ng-model="question.answer">
</select>
</div>
```